# How can I store localStorage data in one object?

Tags: javascript

Now I got something like this, instead of creating `new-info: {"name": "name", "description": "mydescription"}` it deletes the previous new-info and just adds for example
`new-info: "test"` How can I make this to be one object of values?

```js
  function setName(value) {
      this.name = value
      localStorage.setItem('new-info', JSON.stringify(this.name))
    },
  function setDescription(value) {
      this.description = value
      localStorage.setItem('new-info', JSON.stringify(this.description))
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you are not assigning the required object to localStorage, but rather the string property, meaning you are overwriting the key `new-info` with a string. Try saving the entire object instead, like this:

```js
const info = {
  name: '',
  description: ''
};

function setName(value) {
  info.name = value;
  saveToStorage();
};
function setDescription(value) {
  info.description = value;
  saveToStorage();
};
function saveToStorage() {
  localStorage.setItem('new-info', JSON.stringify(info));
}
```

Comment: @zeus - did you find this helpful, or is it not quite working as expected? If it is helpful, please mark as the accepted answer.